# Returning an array of structs without pointers in C

Tags: c

I have been working my way through Kochan's "Programming in C" 3rd Edition on my own to get ready for grad school next year, and I am stuck for the first time. I am a chapter away from pointers, yet the exercise at the end of this most recent chapter on character strings has a problem that my own research seems to indicate can only be solved by using pointers.

The question has to do with a data structure `entry`:

```
struct entry {
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};
```

We create an array of entries:

```
struct entry dictionary[10] = 
{{"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
 {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
 {"addle", "to become confused"},
 {"aerie", "a high nest"},
 {"ajar", "partially opened"},
 {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
 {"affix", "to append; attach"},
 {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"},
 {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
 {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"}};
```

The prompt reads: "Write a function called `dictionary_sort` that sorts a dictionary, as defined [above], into alphabetical order."

I know there are subtleties to structures and arrays in relation to functions and how functions can take them as arguments or give them back as returned values. The only way that seemed to make sense to me was returning a struct, or specifically an array of structs, but I do not think I applying it correctly here:

```
struct entry dictionary_sort(struct entry dictionary)
```

In total, my current version of the program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry {
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

// Function to compare two character strings

int compare_strings(const char s1[], const char s2[])
{
    int i = 0, answer; 

    while (s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
        i++;

    if (s1[i] < s2[i])
        answer = -1; // s1 < s2
    else if (s1[i] == s2[i])
        answer = 0; // s1 == s2
    else
        answer = 1; // s1 > s2

    return answer;
}

// Function to sort a dictionary structure

struct entry dictionary_sort(struct entry dictionary[])
{
    int dictionary_length = sizeof(dictionary) / sizeof(dictionary[0]);
    int i, j, minimum;
    struct entry temp;

    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_length; i++) {
        minimum = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < dictionary_length; j++) {
            if (compare_strings(dictionary[j].word, 
                                dictionary[minimum].definition) == -1)
                minimum = j;
        }
        temp = dictionary[minimum];
        dictionary[minimum] = dictionary[i];
        dictionary[i] = dictionary[minimum];
    }

    return dictionary;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct entry dictionary[10] =
    {{"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
     {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
     {"addle", "to become confused"},
     {"aerie", "a high nest"},
     {"ajar", "partially opened"},
     {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
     {"affix", "to append; attach"},
     {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"},
     {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
     {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"}};
    int i, dictionary_length = sizeof(dictionary) / sizeof(dictionary[0]);

    dictionary = dictionary_sort(dictionary);

    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_length; i++)
        printf("%s - %s.\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition);

    return 0;
}
```

The string comparison function behaves as expected since it is only returning an integer. I am really at a loss as to how to have the desired functionality without knowledge of pointers. There are enough examples *with* pointers to look up, but I am curious what fundamental principle I am missing here because I feel as though everything else in the book has come very naturally to me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Structures take up a fixed amount of memory.  If they are next to each other contiguously in memory, they form an array.  You can get to the nth structure in this array (the first n being 0, located at the first byte of the array) by `n * k`, where `k` is the size of the struct.  That's all `a[i]` means anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you for your reply. Is the only way to make a function then that returns one element of the arranged `struct` array at a time? It just seems inefficient to have to rearrange it for each call. I know this is a contrived example, but it seems like he is asking for a function that acts on the whole array at once.

Comment: Well, when you say `a[i]`, you are referring to that particular structure in the array.  What you do with it at that point is entirely up to you.  You can read it, write it, replace it with a different struct, etc.  You can modify it in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to return anything at all, you don't even need explicit pointers, none of that. Sort in-place, and don't reinvent the wheel: use `strcmp()` and `qsort()` ([live demo here](http://ideone.com/BstOez)):

```
struct entry dictionary[] = {
    { "def", "second entry" },
    { "abc", "first entry" },
    { "ghi", "third entry" },
    { "mno", "fifth entry" },
    { "jkl", "fourth entry" }
};

int compare_entry(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const struct entry *ll = l;
    const struct entry *rr = r;
    return strcmp(ll->word, rr->word);
}

#define COUNT(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

qsort(dictionary, COUNT(dictionary), sizeof(dictionary[0]), compare_entry);
```

Comment: That will certainly work. Thank you. I think the spirit of the exercise/book, though, is to avoid using library functions as much as possible.

Comment: @thomasjames That's a no-brainer. They're there because they're well-implemented, tested and performant. Do have an idea about how they work, but don't roll your own ones. Being able to use the standard library fluently is a core competence in C. See, they've reduced your code size by about 70% and improved readability by IDK-how-many-thousands-%.

Comment: @thomasjames While we are at it `printf()` is no more innocent a library function than `strcmp()` or `qsort()`.All are standard C library functions.It's just that some are used much more frequently than others.

Comment: @H2CO3, if I ever get to the point where I do larger projects, then yes. In this one the author specifically asked that we use a custom string comparison function from another exercise, though. That said, in general, I absolutely would agree. I think my inner OCD is coming out here.

Comment: @SheerFish, it is just that the book is sequential, and qsort hasn't been covered yet. I know I am being a bit ridiculous, and I apologize.

Comment: @thomasjames In that case, at least please try to implement your own `strcmp()` a bit better. Those explicit `if`s are horrible, why not `return s1[i] - s2[i];` at the end, for example?

Comment: @thomasjames If it's "not covered", you can always [fire up the docs.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) And don't fear that you be ridiculous, you aren't, just give up some of this 1D attitude ;)

Comment: @H2CO3, point well taken. I was just following the book to the letter for that function. I'll think outside the box a bit more next time.

Comment: @thomasjames Yap, that's needed for programming :)

Comment: @H2CO3, also, thank you for the live demo. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @thomasjames Please don't apologize.  The poster of this answer is wrong.  If it's an exercise to learn something, that doesn't mean digging up a function from a library.  It's good to know qsort() exists though.

Answer (score 1):

While not perfect and still requiring the explicit definition of pointers, this answer is within the scope of the problem and the book by not just calling libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry {
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

// Function to compare two character strings

int compare_strings(const char s1[], const char s2[])
{
    int i = 0, answer; 

    while (s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
        i++;

    if (s1[i] < s2[i])
        answer = -1; // s1 < s2
    else if (s1[i] == s2[i])
        answer = 0; // s1 == s2
    else
        answer = 1; // s1 > s2

    return answer;
}

// Function to sort a dictionary structure

void dictionary_sort(struct entry *dictionary, int dictionary_length)
{
    int i, j, minimum;
    struct entry temp;

    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_length - 1; i++) {
        minimum = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < dictionary_length; j++) {
            if (compare_strings(dictionary[j].word, 
                                dictionary[minimum].word) == -1)
                minimum = j;
        }
        temp = dictionary[minimum];
        dictionary[minimum] = dictionary[i];
        dictionary[i] = temp;
    }
}

// Prints the dictionary in its current state

void print_dictionary(struct entry *dictionary, int dictionary_length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < dictionary_length; i++) {
        printf("%s - %s.\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition);
    }
}

// Demostrates the dictionary_sort function

int main(void)
{
    struct entry dictionary[10] =
    {{"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
     {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
     {"addle", "to become confused"},
     {"aerie", "a high nest"},
     {"ajar", "partially opened"},
     {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
     {"affix", "to append; attach"},
     {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"},
     {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
     {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"}};

    int i, dictionary_length = sizeof(dictionary) / sizeof(dictionary[0]);

    print_dictionary(&dictionary, dictionary_length);
    printf("\nSorting...\n\n");
    dictionary_sort(&dictionary, dictionary_length);
    print_dictionary(&dictionary, dictionary_length);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function parameter with `[]`, you already use pointers. The function definition

```
int compare_strings(const char s1[], const char s2[])
```

is functionally the same as

```
int compare_strings(const char *s1, const char *s2)
```

Same with `struct entry dictionary_sort(struct entry dictionary[])`.

Since you get a pointer to `struct entry` as parameter `dictionary`, `return dictionary` returns a *pointer* to `struct entry` as well.

And all changes you make to `dictionary` are already visible outside, because you modify the array itself and not some local array.

Comment: so if I made it a function `void dictionary_sort(struct entry dictionary[])` it would effect dictionary globally back in main without having to return anything?

Comment: @thomasjames It already does so. The return type doesn't change anything. In your case though, it doesn't compile, because the return types conflict `struct entry` vs `struct entry*`.

Answer (score 0):

A statement like `"Returning an array of structs without pointers in C"` is a paradox in C because the only way to pass or return an array in C is through pointers.Even though it may seem that in something like `char *foo(char arr_demo[]){}` an array is being passed, essentially it's a pointer being passed as it reduces to `char *foo(char *arr_demo){}`.

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to return a fixed size (known at compile time) array by wrapping it in a struct, so returning a pointer is not the *only* way. I'd call this passing/returning an array, because that's what happens, even if that array is inside a struct. It's just a very bad approach usually, so it does not get used much.